# ARM assembly puzzle

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, puzzle

First of all, I'm not sure if solution even exists. I spent more than a couple of hours trying to come up with one, so beware.

### The problem:

r1 contains an arbitrary integer, flags are *not* set according to its value. Set r0 to 1 if r1 is 0x80000000, to 0 otherwise, using only two instructions.

It's easy to do that in 3 instructions (there are many ways), however doing it in 2 seems very hard, and may very well be impossible.

Comment: Any restrictions on architecture version? That could affect whether or not there is a solution.

Comment: it's more of a question of curiosity now for me, not of a practical application, so any arch is fine

Comment: Thought about this a good amount over the last day, and I'm pretty confident it's not possible.  Lots of ways to get there in 3 instructions, but as asked, I can't think of a way to do it in 2.

Answer (score 6):

something like

```
SMMUL r0,r1,r1
MOV r0,r0,lsr #30
```

Comment: nice answer, SMMUL has four operands, yes?  maybe SMMUL r2,r0,r1,r1.  I think r0 will end up with 1,2, or 3 though if the msbit of r1 is set.

Comment: Arm's doccumentation describes SMMUL as signed top word multiplication, so it's listed as a 3 register opcode. My thinking is: 0x80000000 x 0x80000000. gives 0x40000000 in the top word, so a 30 place shift will bring that bit30 to bit0. (No arm V6 architecture here to test it on)

Comment: @dwelch: you're thinking of SMULL. SMMUL is an ARMv6 instruction that just gives the top 32 bits of the result.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.  Either way though, the upper two bits of your result can be 1, 2, or 3 depending on the other bits in r1, you still need a third instruction to orr those lower two bits together to get the result.

Comment: try a 3, 4, 8, bit multiplier (since a 32x32 will take you a while) and look at what happens to the upper bits of the result for the cases where the msbit of the operand is a 1.  Look at 0xF times 0xF = 0xE1, both upper bits are set.  0x8 * 0x8 = 0x40 only one of the upper bits is set.

Comment: @dwelch: the largest result you can get from squaring a signed number is (-2^31)^2 = 2^62; any value other than 0x80000000 will give a smaller (and non-negative) result. In your 4-bit example, you're doing an unsigned multiplication; a signed multiplication will interpret 0xF as -1, giving a result of 0x01. So these two instructions do indeed give the correct result, with no need for a third.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: That is pretty cool...0x80000000 is the only case where SMMUL takes the same number with the msbit set and the result has the msbit set.  SMULL should be able to be used for pre ARMV6 cores so long as you are careful with the operands. SMULL r2,r0,r1,r1 or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial solution that gives the correct answer in the top bit of `r0`, so it is available as a shifter operand (`r0 lsr #31`).

```
; r0 = r1 & -r1
rsb r0, r1, #0
and r0, r0, r1
```

This works because `0` and `0x80000000` are the only numbers that retain their sign bits when negated. I'm fairly sure an exact solution is impossible.

EDIT: no, it's not impossible. See Martin's answer.

Comment: Nice trick with the negation. Unfortunately extracting the highest bit requires the 3rd instruction (or modification of the instruction that uses the result, which's not always possible).

Comment: I thought about this problem the whole day and I'm sure a two instruction solution is impossible as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
adds  r0, r1, #0x80000000 ; if r1 is 0x80000000, r0 will now hold 0
movne r0, #1              ; otherwise, set r0 to 1
```

This is equivalent to:

```
unsigned int r0, r1;
r0 = r1 + 0x80000000; // 32 bits, so top bit will be lost on overflow
if (r0 != 0)
{
    r0 = 1;
}
```

Comment: You inverted the result: the problem specification required 1 in r0 when r1==0x80000000, and 0 otherwise, and you are setting r0 to 0 on r1==0x80000000 and to 1 otherwise, which is a much simpler problem (that's one of the approaches to get the job done in 3 instructions).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

mov r0,r1,lsr #31

Comment: That will set r0 to 1 as long as r1 has its high bit set. That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: ahh, I see I was looking at the bit not the value

Answer (score 0):

Tough puzzle if one wants to use "fast" instructions.  I can't quite come up with a solution, but can offer a couple more 'notions':

```
; If goal were to have value of zero if $80000000 and something else otherwise:
  adds r0,r1,r1 ; Overflow only if $80000000
  movvc r0,#whatever

; If goal were to have value of $80000000 if $80000000 and zero otherwise
  subs r0,r1,#0  ; Overflow only if $80000000
  movvc r0,#0 ; Or whatever

; If the goal were to have value of $7FFFFFFF if $80000000 and zero otherwise
  adds r0,r1,r1,asr #31 ; Overflow only if $80000000
  movvc r0,#0

; If carry were known to be set beforehand
  addcs r0,r1,r1 ; Overflow only if $80000000 (value is 1)
  movvc r0,#0

; If register r2 were known to hold #1
  adds r0,r1,r1,asr #31
  ; If $80000000, MSB and carry set
  sbc r0,r2,r0,lsr #31
```

None of those is a perfect solution, but they're interesting.